# Qt creator: remote or add project template

Tags: qt, qt-creator

My Qt Creator is version 4.8.2.

I want to remote unnecessary templates(V-Play...) and add new template such as unit test.  How can I do that?

I tried uninstall and install again.  But result was same.
Especially, I don't know why My 'Other Project' template doesn't have **Qt Unit Test** which is default template.

[image]

Comment: *"Qt creator: remote or add project template"* and *"I want to remote unnecessary templates"*. `o.O` Do you mean *"remote"* or *"remove"*?

Comment: p.s. it seems you do not have the unit test package for qt installed. On my system (Linux) one could do something like this `sudo apt install libqt5test5` to install the unit test package and then I can see the "Qt Unit Test" template under the "Other Project" menu. I can't say for sure, but for qt4 something similar should exist. Try by replacing the 5s in my sample command to 4s. Once you install it, restart QtCreator and the template should be there.